# Почему не происходит прокрутка страницы до якоря?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js, vue-router

Vue приложение, используется роутер, `mode: 'history'`
На главной странице перебором массива отрисовываются `router-link` с `:to="{path: '/page', hash: '#'+item}"`

На другой странице содержатся компоненты с обычным текстом. В начале каждого текста заголовок с **id** с соответствующим значением **item** из ссылки, что отрисовываются на главной.

При клике по ссылке, происходит переход на другую страницу `(/page)`, а вот прокрутка до расположения "якоря" не происходит. Точнее, страница прокручивается лишь до середины.

Если же ссылки расположена на самой другой странице, например вверху, то переход по "якорям" происходит (прокрутка до их расположения).

Предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что содержимое компонентов не успевает отобразиться (заполнить пространство на странице определенной высоты, равной содержимому компонента) к моменту срабатывания прокрутки до "якоря".
Так же пробовал в роутер добавлять метод `scrollBehavior`, изменений не наблюдалось.

Буду благодарен за любые предложения реализации данной задачи.

Comment: а там содержимого достаточно, чтобы прокручиваться? А то, может, докручивается до конца страниы и больше некуда

Comment: Да, разумеется. Минимум 1,5 экрана в высоту. Если просто перейти на эту страницу, и в адресной строке браузера добавлять значения якорей после символа #, то работает, с любым якорем. Проблема именно после перехода с других страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645964/vue-js-anchor-to-div-within-the-same-component
https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

думаю тут вы найдете то что ищете)

Comment: Благодарю. Хотя до этого уже просматривал тот вопрос, но сразу не разобрался. Мне помог именно второй ответ в том вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге помогли две вещи:

1. В файле **router** оставил метод

```
scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
```

чтобы при любых переходах страница отображалась сверху;

2. На самой странице (**/page**) в **mounted()** написал

```
let elem = document.querySelector(this.$route.hash)
elem.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' })
```

чтобы страница прокручивалась до места расположения "якоря".

Но все же странно, что решение в документации ко **vue-router** не захотело у меня работать...

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash }
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой. В моем случае ответ оказался прост.
В Vue Router 4 формат возвращаемого объекта из scrollBehavior() изменился по сравнению с тем, что было в Vue Router 3. В частности, свойство объекта selector теперь называется el, как показано в [документах](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior):

```
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return ({
                el: to.hash,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            })
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return (savedPosition);
        } else {
            return {left: 0, top: 0}
        }
    },
```